# How to make workspaces independant in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, workspaces, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04.1 to 18.04 LTS, and instead of ubuntu 18.04, in 16.04 my workspaces were "independent", for example:

**Before:**

If I open a VLC video on my workspace n°1, and open another on the workspace n°2, when I click on VLC on my second workspace's dock, only the video opened on it is shown.

**Now:**

If I do the same thing, I can see the video opened on the first workspace from the second one using the dock.

I tried to search on the internet but didn't know exactly  what to type on the search bar for this case.

Is there any way to make workspaces independent again?